# Blurry images in Chrome / Firefox 28+

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm making a website with a lot of css transform (`rotate:45deg`) but i have few issues with **blurry** text/images.

I did a jsfiddle with an example.
**http://jsfiddle.net/4pjsh/**

In **Chrome**, i added "**hardware acceleration**" to fix the blink/crappy effect during animations but images and text are now always blurry. I searched and tryed lot of things but can't find a way to have them clean.

In **Firefox 27-**, it works fine but since mozilla released **firefox 28/29**, when blocks are animating, images are blurry.At the end of the animation, they come back clean.

Somebody knows how to fix that? if it's possible...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed all rotates, and "started over". Somehow I got rid of the blur in chrome at least.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pjsh/6/

So right now, I'm only rotating like this:

```
.gridd .item {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.gridd .zonelogo img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.gridd .item .blockMore p { //You don't need to be this specific
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
```

Sorry, only had time to do the -webkit ones :)